# Migrate Codeigniter Database to Wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress, codeigniter, migration

I have been trying to import or migrate the Codeigniter database into wordpress. Is that possible to do by any means? I have searched for the solution for it at many places but was unable to find a relevant solution to it.
The real problem is that I have already got a website created in CodeIgniter but now I am making a new site for the same using Wordpress. I need to import all the data and posts contained in the older site into the new one. Maybe database migration can be a easier idea. How will be doing so??

Answer (score 0):

> Codeigniter is a development framework for building applications. WordPress is a system that's already built. 
> I think you could build a large application like WordPress with Codeigniter. But it would then rely on Codeigniter's libraries and framework, so to make that happen I think you would have to rebuild WordPress from scratch. Unless Codeigniter can be used as more of a PHP editing framework as well?
>   Maybe a Codeigniter guru will weigh in.

Source https://wordpress.org/support/topic/codeigniter-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with this is that your CI database is not structured the same as wordpress database.
There are some tools that help you import databases in wordpress like this plugins:
[WP Ultimate CSV Importer Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/)
[Really Simple CSV Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-csv-importer/)
[CSV Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/csv-importer/)
but you will have to provide them the CSV file, that you'll have to export from your CI website. I don't think the import process is very complicated but it's sure easier if you spend some time understanding wordpress databse structure, for that a great resource is the [wordpress code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) and the [Database Description page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description).

The complexity of the CSV file is determined by the objects that you have to import in WordPress here is a check list that its good to have when you start building a CSV file:
1) Are you importing custom post types or just blog entires?
2) Do you have extra info on your import objects that have to be imported as [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)?
3) Do you have users that you need to import? if you do, what roles do you need to have? do you require custom roles (this makes things very complicated) 
4) Do you objects have images attached to them? if they do you'll have to make sure that the import plugin is able to import images!
5) Do you have categories and tags? do they have extra info besides wordpress default info?

When I have to import data to WordPress I try to keep it as simple as possible, I'm trying to import only blog posts and their images if possible depending on the complexity of the initial website I might import categories and tags too but I might split the process before adding this and process them after I have the posts in my wordpress site (this is because I'm more comfortable working with wordpress database and functions then with 3rd party CSV generated files - it might not be your case since you have full access to the initial CI website)

In the end have a look at the plugins I've linked or search yourself some import plugins and check the CSV files they need and try to make the CI website generate a CSV file that is similar with the ones in the examples.

If you have experience with the WordPress databse structure then you can also create a script that loads your data from one database to the other one (I recommend this approach for developers that have experience with both the old websites and WordPress at code/database structure level.

if you can share your databse scheme some extra info might be given.

Answer (score -1):

Export posts from CI database in CSV/XML format or SQL and then change it to CSV accordingly. after that, use WP all import plugin and select the columns correctly. Easy as that..